# HTML Link -> Border

Tags: html, css, hover, border

On our homepage we have several elements as a menupoint.
(Picture + Title + Small description). The problem is that the menuelements always have a border when the mouse is hover. (Even if I hide the border).

You can have a look at: www.scf-software.com

Problem in pictures:

- img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/problem23km5l7qcrp.png
- fotos-hochladen.net/view/problemk1zm7540qh.png

Thank you very much!
I really invested much time, but I couldn't solve it until now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rule that says:

```
a:hover {
   background-color: #c7d1d6;
}
```

The outline you're seeing is the background of your link (the one that contains all the images for the menu) changing due to that CSS rule.

**Edit**
According to Chrome, it's line 28 of site.css

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem. I would like to "like" your comment, but at least i haven't enough points :)

Comment: @ThomasChristof but you can surely select it as the right answer if that was the case, can't you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a class on your A tags? Then in CSS declare the hover state and tell it no border?

```
<a class="something" href="#">
        <div class="menuePoint">
            <div class="menuePointIcon">U</div>
            <div class="menuePointTitle">SCF</div>
            <div class="menuePointDesc">Über SCF Software OG</div>
        </div>
        </a>

.something:hover
{background-color:white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must **remove** the

```
a:hover {
    background-color: #C7D1D6;
}
```

from your **site.css** file from **line-28**

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem.